# making all S3 uploads to digitaloceans spaces default to being public

Tags: amazon-s3, digital-ocean, winscp

I'm using DigitalOcean Spaces to upload a bunch of files in different directories. In particular, I'm using WinSCP to do the upload via the S3 protocol.

The problem is that, per WinSCP, all the files are being uploaded with public access to them disabled.

My question is...  how can I make it so that the uploads default to being public when I upload them?